# Instalar versión anterior de Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

Estoy siguiendo un video tutorial de UdeMy donde se usa ASP.NET Core y Vue.js, pero he tenido problemas porque cuando instalo Vue.js y Vuetify y escojo la plantilla los componentes difieren y no los puedo ajustar a lo que se ve en el vídeo, no concuerdan y su visuaización cuando se despliega la página es inconsistente.

Creería que es la versión pero no tengo certeza, en el vídeo se ve que instala @vue/cli@3.0.1 pero mi instalación baja la 3.1.1. Como puedo instalar la versión  @vue/cli@3.0.1.

En la primera imagen se ven las opciones del vídeo y en la segunda imagen las que me despliega el sistema, cuales debo de elegir pra que sean equivalente y no me surjan esos problemas.

Las opciones de instalacion de vuetify difieren con las que mi instalación me despliega, infiero que eso puede influir.[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El cli no tiene nada que ver con el despliegue de componentes. Puede ser alguna diferencia con Vuetify, o que estes olvidando algun css que estaba en el video.

Comment: Verificando el vídeo de la instalación de Vuetify ahí es donde difieren las opciones, me salen otras que en el vídeo no las muestra, entonces es el Vuetify quien me genera la doferencia de código.

Comment: Y como podemos ayudarte con eso?

Comment: @gbianchi, pues me ayudarían indicándome que opciones son equivalentes, en mi instalación salen unas que no muestra la instalación del vídeo y en mi instalación no pregunta por el componente babel.

Comment: Igual eso no deberia mostrarte los componentes diferentes. podes mostrarnos porque decis que se ven diferentes??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí hay algunas diferencias cuando se generan proyectos con versiones distintas de vue-cli. Los parámetros que te pide la línea de comandos para configuración de la instalación de un nuevo proyecto varía de dicha versión.

**Como instalar una versión especifica del vue-cli.**

1. Eliminar tu versión actual de vue-cli.

   `npm uninstall -g @vue/cli`
2. Instalar la versión 3.0.1.

   `npm install -g @vue/cli@3.0.1`.

Con `@3.0.1` indicas la versión especifica del paquete.

Puedes consultar la documentación oficial de vue-cli. [Documentación.](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/installation.html)